# Background image with linear-gradient in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an image saved in my assets folder, it's a banner image and i'm displaying some text over it. I was using a linear gradient to make the text more readable and it looked nice, for some reason this just stopped working. (I didn't even change anything)

this is what I think SHOULD work:

```
background-image: url('banner_img.jpg'), ( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) )
```

but Rails will only load the image if I use:

```
background: image-url('banner_img.jpg')
```

adding a linear gradient to this does not work.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: you mean when you added the helper `image-url` it stopped working ?

Comment: yes, background: image-url('banner_img.jpg') works  -- but background: ( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), image-url('banner_img.jpg') does not

Comment: I realised my issue - I stupidly missed out 'linear gradient'...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class='foo'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://adityamehta.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Sky-Blue-Sky.jpg');
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.foo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
  mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

Look [codepan](http://codepen.io/aruprakshit/pen/KpLpvE).